# Append Anchor tags to span in Jquery

Tags: jquery, append

I created a `span` tag and I want to append `anchor` tags to it

```
var span = "<span></span>";
// docs are fetched from Dynamics 365 
$(docs).each(function(i, value) {
  var doc = value.Attributes;
  var blob = b64ToBlob(doc.documentbody, doc.mimetype);
  var a = $("<a></a>");
  a.prop("href", URL.createObjectURL(blob));
  a.prop("download", doc.filename);
  a.prop("target", "_parent");
  a.html(doc.subject);

  $(span).append(a);
});

// render span as "<span><a href='..'></a> ... <a href='..'></a></span>"
```

I want to render the span as a long string since I'm using it inside a datatable.

But nothing gets appended to the span tag. What could be the problem with this piece of code?

Comment: Try with `span = $(span).append(a);`

Comment: What do you mean with "datatable"? Is it an html element or a table within a database?

Comment: @Reporter As in Bootstrap4-DataTables. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: Then create a minimal runnable example to reproduce youtr problem.

Comment: @Jadenkun did you try what I wrote?

Comment: Eventually I went with a different approach. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.attr()](https://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Example:

```
$("#id").attr("href", URL.createObjectURL(blob));
```